# How do I resolve a Stream Not Found error in Snowflake that only appears for Task Runs?

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I'm getting an error when a query consuming a stream is being executed by a task. The error **only** appears when the query is being executed via a task.

In querying `information_schema.task_history`, I can see the task status is `FAILED` with error code `091111`. I haven't been able to find any documentation on error codes so I'm mostly relying on the error message
`Stream my_stream not found.`

The stream is being created with `SHOW_INITIAL_ROWS` parameter set to `TRUE`. This is because the source table has existed for quite some time and I would like the task to handle the past data in addition to incoming data.

**What I've Noticed**

`SYSTEM$STREAM_HAS_DATA` returns False until a new CDC becomes apparent. Since `SHOW_INITIAL_ROWS` is set to `TRUE`, when I query the stream I get the same number of rows returned as when I query the table itself. However, `SYSTEM$STREAM_HAS_DATA` still returns False.

**What I've Tried**

1. Can query the stream

I've confirmed the task owner has access to the stream by using this role and querying.

`SELECT * FROM my_stream LIMIT 5; -- Works.`

This confirms that the stream does in fact exist.

2. Executing an UPDATE command does make `SYSTEM$STREAM_HAS_DATA` return `TRUE` with all the rows (and not just the diff from this one command).
3. I can run the SQL of the task itself. Going into the History page, I can copy and paste the query and run it.

This confirms the query itself works.

4. Subsequent changes are in fact handled by the task.

**Where I Need Help**

- I need the task to handle the stream without manual intervention and execution to make the stream looks like it exists

I'm assuming that by executing the query manually, something is happening behind the scene that makes this stream accessible. [An example of this would be a stream being created on at able by its owner enables change tracking on that table.](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/sql/create-stream.html#usage-notes)
However, I've been unable to find what would be causing a scenario where a stream is unfindable until queried.

**Update: Step by Step Instructions to Reproduce Bug**

Ran into the bug where it's much easier to see what's going on. From there, was able to come up with step by step instructions to reproduce the bug.

*First, without show_initial_rows*

```
use database stream_database;
use schema stream_schema;
create table test_table (a integer);
create stream test_stream on table test_table;

select * from test_stream;  -- Works
select * from stream_database.stream_schema.test_stream;  -- Works
 
use database different_database;  -- Use a different database
select * from stream_database.stream_schema.test_stream;  -- Still works
```

*Now, with show_initial_rows set to TRUE*

```
use database stream_database;
use schema stream_schema;


create table test_table (a integer);
create stream test_stream on table test_table  **show_initial_rows** = true;

select * from test_stream;  -- Works
select * from stream_database.stream_schema.test_stream;  -- Works
 
use database different_database;
select * from stream_database.stream_schema.test_stream;  -- Error is raised!

select * from stream_database.stream_schema.test_table;  -- Works, so there is still access to the table.
```

(Assumed) Expected Behavior: Enabling show_initial_rows on a stream should not change the scope in which the stream is accessible.

Comment: Based on your update from today and code sample you provided, it seems you hit similar issue I posted yesterday [Snowflake - “Stream not found” when accessing using fully-qualified name from different schema](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67010830/snowflake-stream-not-found-when-accessing-using-fully-qualified-name-from-di)

Comment: @LukaszSzozda That does seem to be the same issue. I also just heard back from Snowflake -- they said the fix is awaiting deployment, so it should hopefully be fixed soon

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has been confirmed by Snowflake support to be a bug. They've opened a ticket internally to address it.

Will try to post an update here upon resolution.

**UPDATE 2021-04-30**

Snowflake has incorporated a fix applied to versions >= 5.15.
You can check your version by querying `SELECT CURRENT_VERSION();` Barring any rollbacks, this should apply to everyone.

The update has fixed the `Stream not found` error with code `091111` for me. It has not, however, fixed the SYSTEM$STREAM_HAS_DATA returning False until a new change has been made to the source table.

**UPDATE 2021-05-26**

A fix for SYSTEM$STREAM_HAS_DATA returning False for initial rows has been put in place for versions >= 5.20