# Snowflake - "Stream not found" when accessing using fully-qualified name from different schema

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Let's assume we have schema `TestA` that contains table `TestA.Tab` and stream `TestA.TabStream`:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE SCHEMA TestA;

USE SCHEMA TestA;
CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE TestA.Tab AS SELECT 1 AS c;
CREATE OR REPLACE STREAM TestA.TabStream ON TABLE TestA.Tab SHOW_INITIAL_ROWS = TRUE;

SELECT * FROM TestA.TabStream;
/*
C   METADATA$ACTION METADATA$ISUPDATE   METADATA$ROW_ID
1   INSERT          FALSE               ....
*/
```

Now when accessing stream using exactly the same query `SELECT * FROM TestA.TabStream;` but from context of different schema:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE SCHEMA TestB;

USE SCHEMA TestB;
SELECT * FROM TestA.TabStream;
```

I got:

> Stream TABSTREAM not found.

The stream definitely exists:

```
SHOW STREAMS IN DATABASE;
-- name         schema_name
-- TABSTREAM    TESTA
```

Is there some kind of limitation that prohibit from using fully-qualified name for stream?

Comment: I'm not able to reproduce this issue on my system.  Are you using the same role throughout all of these commands?

Comment: @MikeWalton Yes, the role is the same for all queries(single worksheet).

Comment: I am able to reproduce the issue. Which role are you using @LukaszSzozda  and MikeWalton? I am using SYSADMIN

Comment: It looks like a(-n interesting) bug to me.

Comment: @FrancescoQuaratino The rule is custom one, but it resembles SYSADMIN.

Comment: Hi @LukaszSzozda are you going to submit a Support Case? https://community.snowflake.com/s/article/How-To-Submit-a-Support-Case-in-Snowflake-Lodge please let me know, If not I am happy to do that

Comment: @FrancescoQuaratino Please free to do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is no longer reproducible and stream is accessible from different schema:

```
SELECT current_version();
-- 5.16.1

CREATE OR REPLACE SCHEMA TestA;

USE SCHEMA TestA;
CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE TestA.Tab AS SELECT 1 AS c;
CREATE OR REPLACE STREAM TestA.TabStream ON TABLE TestA.Tab SHOW_INITIAL_ROWS = TRUE;

SELECT * FROM TestA.TabStream;
/*
C   METADATA$ACTION METADATA$ISUPDATE   METADATA$ROW_ID
1   INSERT          FALSE               ....
*/

CREATE OR REPLACE SCHEMA TestB;

USE SCHEMA TestB;
SELECT * FROM TestA.TabStream
/*
C   METADATA$ACTION METADATA$ISUPDATE   METADATA$ROW_ID
1   INSERT          FALSE               ....
*/
```